# NSTextView in NSAlert has no scrollbars

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm trying to add an NSTextView into an NSAlert so that the user can type into it.  However, the scrollbars never appear, no matter how much the user types.  What is going on?

Here is the code I'm using, and a screenshot of the dialog that appears:

```
NSAlert *alert = [NSAlert alertWithMessageText:@"Enter stuff here:"
                                 defaultButton:@"OK"
                               alternateButton:nil
                                   otherButton:nil
                     informativeTextWithFormat:@""];



NSTextView *textView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 200, 50)];
[alert setAccessoryView:textView];
[alert runModal];
```

[image: Screenshot of lack of scrollbars]

Comment: You need to place the NSTextView inside a NSScrollView

Comment: Oops, I thought it was automatically included with an NSTextView.  If you want to create your response as a separate answer I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to place the NSTextView inside a NSScrollView.

Apple describes the process in [this document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/TextUILayer/Tasks/TextInScrollView.html).

The main code from there is:

```
NSScrollView *scrollview = [[NSScrollView alloc]
            initWithFrame:[[theWindow contentView] frame]];
NSSize contentSize = [scrollview contentSize];

[scrollview setBorderType:NSNoBorder];
[scrollview setHasVerticalScroller:YES];
[scrollview setHasHorizontalScroller:NO];
[scrollview setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable |
            NSViewHeightSizable];
theTextView = [[NSTextView alloc] initWithFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0,
            contentSize.width, contentSize.height)];
[theTextView setMinSize:NSMakeSize(0.0, contentSize.height)];
[theTextView setMaxSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[theTextView setVerticallyResizable:YES];
[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:NO];
[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:NSViewWidthSizable];

[[theTextView textContainer]
            setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(contentSize.width, FLT_MAX)];
[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:YES];
[scrollview setDocumentView:theTextView];
[theWindow setContentView:scrollview];
[theWindow makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
[theWindow makeFirstResponder:theTextView];
[[theTextView enclosingScrollView] setHasHorizontalScroller:YES];
[theTextView setHorizontallyResizable:YES];
[theTextView setAutoresizingMask:(NSViewWidthSizable | NSViewHeightSizable)];
[[theTextView textContainer] setContainerSize:NSMakeSize(FLT_MAX, FLT_MAX)];
[[theTextView textContainer] setWidthTracksTextView:NO];
```

Answer (score 0):

In the xib inside attributes inspector just enable the vertical and horizontal scrollers.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for a way to do it programmatically, though.  Should have specified that in my question.